# After suspend I cannot control the brghtness of the screen

Tags: suspend, brightness

Neither the keyboard keys not the control panel fixes this issue. The only solution is to reboot, which is a pain. How do I fix this?

SPecs:

- Toshiba Portege z935
- Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a Portege R935 in 12.04, and I'm dealing with it with this (not so elegant) workaround:

- as root (not with `sudo` but actually changing user: `su root`), change the value in
  `sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

  for example:

  ```
  echo 2937 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
  ```

**Warning**: these brightness values aren't between `0` and `7` (as the ones in the other directory), but between `284` and `4539`, or something like that.

Hope it helps.